# How can I make this python script walk through a directory tree?

Tags: python

I have a python script

```
$ cat ~/script.py
import sys
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse(sys.argv[1])
title = doc.find('//title')
title.text = span2.text.strip()
print etree.tostring(doc)
```

I can run the script on an individual file by issuing something like

```
$ python script.py foo.html > new-foo.html
```

My problem is that I have a directory `~/webpage` that contains hundreds of `.html` files scattered throughout sub-directories. I would like to run `~/script.py` on all of these html files. I am currently doing this with

```
$ find ~/webpage/ -name "*.html" -exec sh -c 'python ~/script.py {} > {}-new' \;
```

However, this creates a new file for each html file in `~/webpage` and I actually want the original file edited.

Is this possible to do from within python? Maybe with something like `os.walk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os

def process(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as readonly_file:
        print "Do something with %s ,size %d" % (file_name, len(readonly_file.read()))

def traverse(directory, callback=process):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
            callback(path)

print traverse('./')
```

please rewrite process function according to you own logic, this callback accept absolute path as only parameter.

if you want process specific file only:

```
def traverse(directory, callback=process, file_type="txt"):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
            if path.endswith(file_type):
                callback(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `os` module in python has a function specifically for walking down directories](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

```
import os
import sys
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse


def parse_file(file_name):
    doc = parse(file_name)
    title = doc.find('//title')
    title.text = span2.text.strip()
    print etree.tostring(doc)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/webpages'):
    for name in files:
        parse_file(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: So making these changes removes the errors but how can I use this to save the edits to the files?

Comment: Well you could write the document being generated to a file. I'll update my answer with an example.